Survival analysis for survey (case-control?) data
I have a dataset comprising approximately 500 patients with about 10 different diseases, potentially with correlated outcomes, and 200 healthy controls. Patient data is sourced from the hospital, while control data comes from volunteers and is not matched. We have comprehensive records of various life events, including specific dates (e.g., age of first-time illegal drug use) and dates of diagnosis for both patients and controls. However, no sampling weights are available.
As a first step, I plan to apply a Cox proportional hazards (PH) model to each disease individually, using birth as the time reference (time = 0). The events are binary (whether a disease is diagnosed or not). The dataset includes around 10 potential predictors, such as sex, race, and education, with some covariates potentially being time-dependent (e.g., marriage history and employment).
(A) Given that cases are oversampled, can I weight the sample based on prevalence or incidence rates from external sources? (A link of previous papers doing this will be extremely helpful.).
(B) Can this study be considered a case-cohort study, even though it does not fit the traditional definition?
(C) While logistic regression is typically used for case-control studies (yielding only odds ratios), is there an analogous approach in survival analysis for dealing with this type of data?
Thank you!

Please edit the question to clarify the Cox model(s) that you intend to use. You say that disease is the outcome, but how are you handling the "various diseases"? Separate models for each disease, time to first disease, multi-state model, ...? What is the time reference (time = 0) for the survival analysis? Date of birth, date of entry into study, some calendar date, ...? What/how many predictors are you intending to use? How many events (development of disease) are there? That's much more important than the number of cases.

I have edited the questions. Please inform me if further editing is needed.

Thanks. Please also add how many events of each type are in the data set. Any disease with less than 100 to 150 events will pose problems if you try to fit a model with 10 predictors.

The answer from Sextus Empiricus (+1) gets to a major issue that you raised, whether you could use something like case-cohort analysis for your study. You can't.
Second, you seem to want to be able to extend the results of your Cox proportional hazards regression to a broader, more representative population. There are more issues with that than can be explained here, even for a descriptive model that doesn't attempt to get at causal inference. Chapter 10 of Therneau and Grambsch discusses many of those issues, based on the implicit assumption that your model is correct.
There are additional issues with your study design that need to be addressed.
Left truncation. Unless you have information on all individuals available since the date of birth, your time values are necessarily left truncated. For example, someone for whom you have the first data at an age of 27 provides no information about those in the population at younger ages.
Although that's nicely handled by the counting-process data format that you will presumably be using for time-varying covariates (the start time for each time intervals is treated as a left truncation), with the time = 0 reference at birth you probably will have very little information about young ages. Klein and Moeschberger discuss that problem in Section 4.6. In practice, you might have to analyze data conditional upon having survived to some age at which you have enough data to be useful.
An analog to odds ratios. I think this is implicit in the answer from Sextus Empiricus, but I'll but put it in my own words. As you recognize, logistic regression coefficients can provide useful information about odds ratios associated with a difference in predictor values, even when the intercept can't be generalized to the population (as in a case-control study).
The analog in a Cox proportional hazard model is the hazard ratio, the relative event hazard associated with a difference in predictor values. Insofar as you have a valid model those hazard ratios will provide similarly useful information. The analog to the intercept of a logistic regression model in such a model is the entire baseline survival curve, which can be estimated once the Cox model is fit but which has discrete steps at the observed event times and might only apply to the population that was sampled.
Volunteers as controls. Hernán and Robins show that relying on volunteers can risk selection bias (Section 8.2).* If your cases were from all those in your records having these diseases while your controls were all volunteers, that might be a problem.
Covariates. If you don't use some form of penalization, then you typically need about 15 events (not individuals) per coefficient that you are estimating in a survival regression. If you want to evaluate 10 predictors in a model for a single disease, you would thus need about 150 individuals with the disease. But if you cut down the number of predictors and omit an outcome-associated predictor from a Cox model you risk omitted-variable bias. See Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies for general background, in particular Chapter 4 for this issue and principled data-reduction approaches to cut down on the (effective) number of predictors.
Time-varying covariates. If you use time-varying covariates, recognize that a Cox model only evaluates the instantaneous values among those at risk at each event time, not any history of the values (unless you define a new covariate related to that history).
Multiple diseases. You recognize that the 10 diseases might be correlated. Individual models for each disease won't handle that and will also lead to a multiple comparisons problem. A multi-state model might be preferable, treating each disease as a separate type of event.
I strongly recommend that you consult with a statistician having experience in survival analysis, to see what you might be able to glean reliably from such a study.

*That reference is a valuable introduction to the problems of moving beyond simple description of data to causal inference. Chapter 17 is specifically on causal survival analysis, and the last 5 chapters deal with the problems associated with time-varying treatments.

Thank you! Regarding the time-varying covariates: What is the best method to model the history of the values? For instance, I am imagining that if someone is smoking at age $[t_0, t_1]$, it will contribute to the hazard to get lung cancer at time $t_2$ by $\int_{t_2-t_1}^{t_2-t_0}\lambda(t)dt$. Maybe nonparametric/functional data would work here?

Also, multi-state models I know are usually the same disease with different kinds of severity. If I have 10 diseases, and consider all possibilities of disease status, wouldn't it be too many states to fit the model?

@failedstatistician in principle there's no problem with developing a multi-state model with lots of states. I doubt that you will have enough events to fit such a model reliably from your data, however. There's no general rule for devising covariates that include the history of variables; that depends on your understanding of the subject matter and what that means for how the past history of some variable might influence the current risk of an event.

I thought for a while. Suppose that the covariate is smoking. The simplest method I can think of is to use the cumulative time of smoking, or the proportion of smoking time out of life span. However, I would like a model-based approach because: (A) If someone is aged 55, I don't think that smoking from 20-25 has the same risk as 45-50. Intuitively, more recent smoking has higher risk (B) If the history is too recent, it may have a smaller effect due to censoring. I don't think that if I smoke today, it will increase the probability that I will be diagnosed with cancer tomorrow.

(Continue) Of course, I can write a parametric model, do a grid search on the parameters and select those with AIC or something. But I am still thinking about, say, if $\lambda(t)=\alpha Exp(-\beta t)$, how to actually fit $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

@failedstatistician there are "joint models" that combine mixed models of covariates along with survival analysis. This answer and this answer contain links to further information. The choice of how to incorporate covariate history into such a model is a function of subject-matter knowledge.

Thank you! Just skimmed a course slide. https://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/ESP72.pdf I guess that I will try the extended Cox model first. My time-dependent covariates (like smoking) is typically measured before the event, so they are mostly exogenous. Or maybe a diagnosis of a disease makes me depressed and smoke more, but I think I can simply delete that part of the data without losing much information.

Here is an explanation of the mathematics behind a case-cohort study.
Below we see a sketch for a simulation of data in a cohort study among 2500 people with an 'outcome' sick vs not sick and this is being studied as a function of a variable 'type' which has 3 levels.

If we study the entire cohort then we would have a contingency table like
$$\begin{array}{r|ccc}
&\text{type 1}&\text{ type 2}&\text{ type 3} \\ \hline
\text{sick}&19&43&54 \\
\text{not sick}&840&798&746\\
\\
\text{sum}&859&841&800\\
\end{array}$$
This requires to measure the types among all 2500 patients.
The alternative with a case-cohort study is to have a sub-cohort like the 200 people in the 10 by 20 square in the lower left corner and only determine the types in the sub cohort and the positive cases. Then the table will look like:
$$\begin{array}{r|ccc|ccc}
&\rlap{\text{rest of cohort}}&&&\rlap{\text{sub cohort}}\\
&\text{type 1}&\text{ type 2}&\text{ type 3} 
&\text{type 1}&\text{ type 2}&\text{ type 3} \\ \hline
\text{sick}&17&35&50 &2&8&4\\
\text{not sick}&\color{pink}{768}&\color{pink}{732}&\color{pink}{698}&72&66&48\\
\\
\text{sum}&\color{pink}{785}&\color{pink}{767}&\color{pink}{748}&74&74&52\\
\end{array}$$
Here, the pink numbers are not observed. And we only know the 12 data values in black.
These values can be modelled based on the probabilities of the disease occuring or not for the types, $p_1,p_2,p_3$, as well as the odds of being outside the sub-cohort $o_{\neg sub}$ and the numbers in the subcohort $n_1,n_2,n_3$.
$$\begin{array}{r|ccc|ccc}
&\rlap{\text{rest of cohort}}&&&\rlap{\text{sub cohort}}\\
&\text{type 1}&\text{ type 2}&\text{ type 3} 
&\text{type 1}&\text{ type 2}&\text{ type 3} \\ \hline
\text{sick}&p_1n_1o_{\neg sub}&p_2n_2o_{\neg sub}&p_3n_3o_{\neg sub} &p_1n_1&p_2n_2&p_3n_3 \\
\text{not sick}&-&-&-&(1-p_1)n_1&(1-p_2)n_2&(1-p_3)n_3 \\
\hline
\text{total}&-&-&-&n_1&n_2&n_3
\end{array}$$
The above is the case for a contingency table, the same may be done for a proportional hazards model. Now the computations are potentially not including those bins anymore (e.g. if the variables are continuous instead of categorical), but then we have all the $n_i=1$ and it works the same. For a relative hazards model, you compute the odds of occuring in a specific individual given that somebody got sick, and you see that there is an additional factor $o_{\neg sub}$ if that individual is outside the sub-cohort.


(A)

can I weight the sample based on prevalence or incidence rates from external sources?

The weighing occurs based on the odds of being in the sub-cohort.

(B)

Can this study be considered a case-cohort study?

The case-cohort study selects a sub-cohort that is independent from being sick or not. Your controls may have been selected depending on whether they are not sick. Possibly you may perform some similar corrections but it is not the same. You can not make the 2nd table like above where you can compute the prevalences of the types, and you can not make the step from contingency to proportional hazards in case of continuous variables (where there are no categories and no clearly defined prevalences).

(C)

is there an analogous approach in survival analysis

Because it is simpler, I have made an example with a contingency table. So that is one analogous approach. The problem with this alternative is that it doesn't work with continuous variables and with variable exposure times among subjects.
Beyond that, there are many others. Any alternative to relative hazards (e.g. an accelerated time model) can give an analogues approach. You just add the factor $o_{\neg sub}$ for the risk.



Code for image
set.seed(1)

n = 50
type = sample(1:3, n^2, replace = TRUE)
x = rep(1:n,n)
y = rep(1:n,each=n)
p = type/50
sick = rbinom(n^2,1,p)

par(mar = c(1,1,1,1))
plot(x,y,pch=20+type, cex = 1,
     xlab = "", ylab = "",
     xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
     bg = 0+2*sick, bty = "n", xlim = c(0,n+5), ylim = c(0,n+5))

legend(0.5,n+5, c("type 1", "type 2", "type 3"), pch = c(21,22,23), ncol = 3)

legend(30,n+5, c("sick", "not sick"), pt.bg = c(2,0), pch = 21, ncol = 2)

lines(c(0,10,10,0,0)+0.5,
      c(20,20,0,0,20)+0.5, lty = 2, lwd = 2)

sub = (x<=10)*(y<=20)

table(sick, paste0(sub,type))
table(sick, paste0(type))  


I think you can just build binary classifiers to build your discrete-time survival model: https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-022-01679-6
See especially the discussion around figure 1) to understand how you need to resample your data for a discrete-time survival model

This approach is super flexible. I miss the discussion of discrete-time survival models a lot! For a calibrated classifier the predicted score is the hazard probability in a given time interval.
Additionally proper scoring rules and the evaluation metrics of a binary classifier help you judge your model's predictive performance (on hold out test sets)
For your question A) yes: if you know your samples are not drawn according to the population distribution (but are oversampled), you could take care of this when constructing the training set for the classifier - you would then draw samples from the oversampled survival times less frequently.
Some main take-aways from the paper of Krithika Suresh, Cameron Severn & Debashis Ghosh:

"Note that we do not make the assumption that the event indicators within a subject are independent and have a binomial distribution. Instead, we observe that the likelihood function for the discrete-time survival model under non-informative censoring can be represented using a binomial likelihood that assumes independent event indicators"

"Due to the binomial structure of the likelihood function in Eq. (2) the discrete survival time formulation is general and any algorithm that can optimize a binomial log-likelihood can be used to obtain parameter estimates. Thus, within this approach we can apply any method for computing the probability of a binary event and can choose from various binary classification methods, from traditional regression methods to more complex machine learning approaches."



Discrete-time survival models can be very useful, but it's not clear that they would be helpful here. The time values in this study are time since birth, presumably with actual numbers of days (or weeks or months) since birth recorded for outcome dates.

True that here you might not even have to deal with time dependent covariates. Still, these models are not assuming a parametrize-able survival function (like weibull distribution etc.) and are at least equally expressive. So I would say that their simplicity definitely makes them a go-to approach (even for very simple datasets where you could work with a Kaplan-Meier estimator ...)

I don't see anything around Figure 1 about sampling weights. The paper is interesting, though. I think the idea is to discretize the outcome, sacrificing some information but enabling us to use simpler methods like GLM (continuation ratio. model). Am I right?

You are right, the discussion about "sampling" is hidden in a way - but present. So figure 1 tells you how to obtain the "data packages" for your binary classifier (one row on the right hand side) from survival time series (one row on the left hand side). It proposes to slice your time axis into equally spaced intervals - and you have equal weight for all your time survival time series. Instead you could also randomly sample from the time series left with to weights proportional to the length of the time series (or reweight this according to actual frequency expected adjusting for oversampling
